# Passing param to service

Tags: angular

I'm building my api service. I want it to be universal. How to define apiUrl in provider's definition?

Here is my service:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import '/js/admin/rxjs-operators';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    private apiUrl: string = 'http://www.system.local/api/';

    constructor(private http: Http, private apiUrl: string) {
    }

    get(url: string, params): Observable<Response> {
        let requestUrl: string = this.apiUrl + url + this.parseParams(params);
        return this.http.get(requestUrl)
            .map(response => response.json());
    }

    post(url: string, params): Observable<any> {
        let requestUrl: string = this.apiUrl + url;
        return this.http.post(requestUrl, params)
            .map(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

I've tried with service provider but seems that `deps` has to be class:

```
import {ApiService} from "./api.service";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
let apiServiceFactory = (http: Http, apiUrl: string)=> {
    return new ApiService(http, apiUrl);
};

export let apiServiceProvider = {
    provide: ApiService,
    useFactory: apiServiceFactory,
    deps: [Http, 'http://www.wp.pl']
};
```

and in module:
    @NgModule({
        providers: [
            apiServiceProvider
        ]
    })

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 "No provider for String!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628768/angular-2-no-provider-for-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't defined the string as a dependency and rather have a look at `Non-class dependencies` and `Value providers`:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#non-class-dependencies

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#value-provider

Then you'll use `OpaqueToken` to hold the string variable:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#opaquetoken

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html

Comment: So all config values should be seperated from service and injected to that service?

Comment: Yes, have a look at this examaple: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html